# How to fit a polynomial trendline such that only the leading two coefficients are non-zero in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, spreadsheet, regression

I have data on the displacement of an object over time and a cubic trendline fits it very well.
I know that the initial displacement is 0 so I can tick the "set intercept" box.

However, I also know that the initial velocity is 0 so I would like the coefficient of x to be 0 as well. However, I have no idea how to configure the regression to happen in this way.

How can I configure it in this manner?

I'm using Office for Mac.

**EDIT**

To make this clearer,
Suppose we have times:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
and displacements:
[0,2,9,28,69,140,225]

We want to fit a polynomial of 3rd degree to the data which would look like this:
[image]
But because we know the derivative of the function contains the point (0,0) we wish for the coefficient of x, in this case -3.3067, to be 0. How can we configure excel to fit a trendline in this way.

Comment: Could U please [Edit] the post & share some sample data along with expected output, will  help me & others to fix the issue!

Comment: @RajeshS I've done it.

Comment: Another what I've tried,, plot `X-Y Scatter graph` then hit `Data point` on Graph,,, `Right click`,, from Trend line option, select `Polynomial` and set the `order 3`. You may check `Display Equation` also `R Square Value` then U get what u r looking for,,, please confirm if this works for  U ☺

Comment: Hi @PolymorphismPrince, did U try the `LINEST` function ?

Comment: @RajeshS, that `LINEST` function only seems to apply to linear functions whilst I'm dealing with regression.

Comment: @RajeshS, please reread my question. That is not the graph I want. I want the derivative of the trendline to contain (0,0).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105796/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-polymorphismprince).

Answer (score 0):

@RajeshS is right, [LINEST](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) is your answer. But you need to help it. Here is my data and solution.

I've inserted columns where I've calculated time-squared and time-cubed, and I'll use these in my model. I selected the shaded range F2:H6, typed this formula, then array-entered it by holding CTRL+SHIFT while pressing ENTER (don't enter the curly braces, CTRL+SHIFT does that for you):

`{=LINEST(D2:D8,B2:C8,FALSE,TRUE)}`

D2:D8 are the known Y values, B2:C3 are the known X values, FALSE means set the constant to zero, and TRUE means give us the extra rows of statistical feedback. For example, R-squared is 0.99929.

The coefficients of the X values are in reverse order in the first output row of LINEST, and we see the constant is zero, as required.

I used these coefficients to compute the fit in column J, shown in the chart as the orange curve, with the data points as blue markers.

[image: LINEST for poly fit to get 3rd and 2nd order coefficients, with 1st and 0th coefficients equal to zero]